# Premature end of execution due to a vector.push_back() [C++]

Tags: c++, vector, crash, push-back

Good morning everyone, 
I currently have an issue in my code, it crashes without any error output.
I was hopping you could lend me a hand!

The issue occurs when I append an element at a vector, but not at the first iteration always at the second.

Here is my main code:

```
/*Various includes*/
int main(void)
{
  int cmpt = 0;
  std::vector<Commande> _vct;
  Commande cmd;
  while(cmpt < 15)
  {
    cout << "..." << endl;
    _vct.push_back(cmd);
    cout <<" test cmd" << _vct[cmpt].getBytes() << endl;
    cmpt++;

    }

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the object's class that is appened to the vector:

```
Commande::Commande()
{
    bytes="";
    from="";
    type="";
    first_s="";
    last_s="";
    value=-1;
    first_i=-1;
    last_i=-1;
}

Commande::~Commande()
{

}

void Commande::toString()
{
    cout << "=-_-=> from: '" << (this)->getFrom() << "', type: '" << (this)->getType() << "', value: '" << (this)->getValue() << "', bytes: '" << (this)->getBytes() << "'." << endl;
}

void Commande::fromStringToInteger()
{
    (this)->setFirst_i(atoi((this)->getFirst().c_str()));
    (this)->setLast_i(atoi((this)->getLast().c_str()));
}
```

And finally the .h of Commande.cpp:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#ifndef COMMANDE_H_
#define COMMANDE_H_

using namespace std;

class Commande
{
    public:
    Commande();
    virtual ~Commande();
    /*Various geters ans seters*/
    void toString(void);
    void fromStringToInteger();

    private:
    string bytes, from, type, first_s, last_s;
    int value, first_i, last_i;
};

#endif /* COMMANDE_H_ */
```

Thank you all for your time!

Comment: If you say you have a problem with `push_back` it would be helpful if you actually *showed* the problematic code (i.e. the code where you call `push_back`). Please try to create a  [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: Your edited `main` function should not compile either. `_vct` is a *pointer* to an object so you need to use e.g. `_vct->push_back(...)`. It also doesn't solve the memory leak mentioned in my answer. Lastly, do you come from a Java or C# background? In C++ you don't need to use `new` to create objects, just doing e.g. `Commande cmd;` will create a `Commande` object.

Comment: Thank you alll, it is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unrelated to the problem you ask about, but there are many other problems...

For example lets take a closer looks at these lines (excerpt from yout `main` function):

```
while(...)
{
    Commande* cmd = new Commande();
    (this)->appendCmdList(*cmd);
}
```

First of all it should not compile. There's no `this` in non-member functions, only in non-static member functions.

Then you have the memory leak in that you allocate a new `Commande` instance dynamically, but you pass the *instance* (and not the pointer) to the `appendCmdList` function, which means the next time the loop iterates the pointer is lost (as it goes out of scope) and you allocate a new pointer without deleting the previous object, or saving the pointer.

Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's impossible to say anything else.

Comment: Hence, how could I prevent this memory leak?